# CASE statement in JOIN on different Data Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I was wondering if it was possible to use the `CASE` statement on the `JOIN` where the arguments returned from the `CASE` are of a different type.

I try to explain better my question with an example:
I have 2 tables: `TAB1` and `TAB2`.
In a column of `table 2` i have some parameters divided by the pipe character "|".

Depending on the length of the first parameter I need to join with a specific column of the `TAB1`. But in one case the column of `TAB1` has `integer` values, in the other is a `varchar`.

I tried this:

```
select *
from TAB1 as T1
    inner join TAB2 as T2
        on isnull(nullif(substring(T2.PARAM, 0, charindex('|', T2.PARAM, 1)),''), T2.PARAM) =
        case
            when len(isnull(nullif(substring(T2.PARAM, 0, charindex('|', T2.PARAM, 1)),''), T2.PARAM)) >= 16
                then T1.CODFIS
            when isnull(nullif(substring(T2.PARAM, 0, charindex('|', T2.PARAM, 1)),''), T2.PARAM)  < 16
                then T1.ID
        end
```

But it returns an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PAACPP70H41B296Y' to data type int.

Comment: a column / expression / variable can, should and must only by of ONE type! That's what is called bad design...The only option is to convert everything to varchar - needless to say performance and design lack

Comment: @CeOnSql Can be a better solution to use two separete select in UNION?

Comment: I would split the ON statement using AND and OR statements with brackets to separate both comparison statements so that you do not mix up datatypes. Some implicit conversion may still be needed though.

Comment: I agree with CeOnSql; this is a bad database design. If you are interested in parts of the PARAM string, then don't make it a string but separate data instead. So if possible, change your table design.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `T1.ID` is of `integer` type. The data types of `input_expression` and each `when_expressio`n must be the same or must be an **implicit conversion**

```
SELECT *
FROM   TAB1 AS T1
       INNER JOIN TAB2 AS T2
 ON Isnull(NULLIF(Substring(T2.PARAM, 0, Charindex('|', T2.PARAM, 1)), ''), T2.PARAM) 
 = CASE
      WHEN Len(Isnull(NULLIF(Substring(T2.PARAM, 0, Charindex('|', T2.PARAM, 1)), ''), T2.PARAM)) >= 16 THEN T1.CODFIS
      WHEN Isnull(NULLIF(Substring(T2.PARAM, 0, Charindex('|', T2.PARAM, 1)), ''), T2.PARAM) < 16 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), T1.ID)
    END 
                                                                                                      END
```